# How to select only duplicate values, but with one different column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table, which looks like this:

| Aircraft | WorkOrder | EngOrder | Description | PartNo | InstPosition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KHB | 21 | 45 | engine 1 | pw123 | E1 |
| KHB | 21 | 45 | engine 4 | pw123 | E2 |
| KHB | 22 | 45 | engine 2 | pw122 | E1 |
| KBG | 31 | 55 | rotor engine | v123 | E2 |
| KBG | 36 | 51 | engine 9 | v156 | E1 |
| KBG | 31 | 55 | engine comp | v123 | E1 |

I need to select only rows which are similar in **WorkOrder, EngOrder and PartNO**, but different in **InstPosition**. My resulting table should look like this:

| Aircraft | WorkOrder | EngOrder | Description | PartNo | InstPosition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KHB | 21 | 45 | engine 1 | pw123 | E1 |
| KHB | 21 | 45 | engine 4 | pw123 | E2 |
| KBG | 31 | 55 | rotor engine | v123 | E2 |
| KBG | 31 | 55 | engine comp | v123 | E1 |

I tried to use self join, but it returns empty table:

````
SELECT a.* 
FROM table a
INNER JOIN b ON a.WorkOrder = b.WorkOrder 
       AND a.EngOrder = b.EngOrder 
       AND a.PartNO = b.PartNO
       AND a.InstPosition != b.InstPosition ```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I need to select only rows which are similar in WorkOrder, EngOrder and PartNO, but different in InstPosition.

You can do that basically just the way you expressed it in English.  Find any row where there is at least one other row having the same WorkOrder, EngOrder, and PartNo but different InstPosition.

Here's how to translate that to SQL:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   your_table t
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 'similar record'
                FROM   your_table t2
                WHERE  t2.WorkOrder = t.WorkOrder
                AND    t2.EngOrder = t.EngOrder
                AND    t2.PartNo = t.PartNo
                -- simple logic below assumes InsPosition is NOT NULL
                AND    t2.InstPosition <> t.InstPosition 
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join.

This:

> I need to select only rows which are similar in WorkOrder, EngOrder and PartNO, but different in InstPosition.

Sound's like count distinct InstPosition in window for me.

```
select 
Aircraft,
WorkOrder,
EngOrder,
Description,
PartNo,
InstPosition
from
(
  select 
  Aircraft,
  WorkOrder,
  EngOrder,
  Description,
  PartNo,
  InstPosition,
  count(distinct InstPosition) over(partition by WorkOrder, EngOrder , PartNO) as dist_cnt
  from  a
)
where dist_cnt > 1
;
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use an aggregation approach here

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT WorkOrder, EngOrder, PartNO
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY WorkOrder, EngOrder, PartNO
    HAVING MIN(InstPosition) <> MAX(InstPosition)
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.WorkOrder = t1.WorkOrder AND
       t2.EngOrder  = t1.EngOrder  AND
       t2.PartNO    = t1.PartNO;
```

The CTE finds all tuples with `WorkOrder`, `EngOrder`, and `PartNO` having at least 2 different `InstPosition` values.  The outer join then filters the original table.

Answer (score -1):

You could use below solution for that purpose :

```sql
SELECT Aircraft, WorkOrder, EngOrder, Description, PartNo, InstPosition
FROM (
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(DISTINCT InstPosition)OVER(PARTITION BY WorkOrder, EngOrder, PartNo)cnt
  FROM Your_Table t1
) t2
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY WorkOrder, EngOrder, PartNo
;
```

[***demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/zRTC09Pl)